# How to move the focus from a button to another in tvOS?

Tags: menu, focus, tvos, apple-tv

I'm new to tvOS. I would like to have a standard button that once is pressed, it moves the focus to another standard button, how can I do this (if it's possible of course)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Start by overriding the `preferredFocusedView` in your viewController with a custom property:

```
var myPreferredFocusedView:UIView?
override var preferredFocusedView: UIView? {
    return myPreferredFocusedView:UIView
}
```

Then, in your button callback, set the `myPreferredFocusedView` to your next preferred button which should get focus. After that, directly request a focus update:

```
func buttonCallback(){
    myPreferredFocusedView = button2 // button2 is an example 

    /*
        Trigger the focus system to re-query the view hierarchy for preferred
        focused views.
    */
    setNeedsFocusUpdate()
    updateFocusIfNeeded()
}
```

This should update the focus system to your other button.

Comment: Thank you so much Antoine. It works fine, the only problem I get now is that when leaving the view and then come back, the focus is lost and I need to use the arrow keys (or to drag on the remote) to get any button to have focus. I will try to study more about this...

Comment: You can use the same code. Just make sure you set the `preferredFocusedView` and request a focus update at the viewWillAppear

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to do something like the following, when buttonA (for example) has focus:

```
buttonB.setNeedsFocusUpdate()
viewController.setNeedsFocusUpdate()
```

This only works if they're on the same level in the view hierarchy, though. If not then you probably need to chain the calls to `setNeedsFocusUpdate` all the way up the hierarchy or something...

[Read more here](https://medium.com/airbnb-engineering/mastering-the-tvos-focus-engine-f8a13b371083)