# TvOS focus engine skip cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, tvos, focus-engine

I have UITableView where 1 cell has `userInteractionEnabled = false` so can't be focused. When user try to focus this cell I want to focus button under the table. How to achieve it ? I tried `didUpdateFocus`and other methods but they are not called.

Comment: Provide more context for a better clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Use `canBecomeFocused` on that 1 cell: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622584-canbecomefocused

Comment: I guess it is not what i meant. My problem is that when User want to focus cell at indexPath 0 then I want to change focus on button below tableView

Comment: on `didUpdateFocus` you can check if the next cell is the one at IndexPath.row == 0. Then you can use `preferredFocusedView` on your ViewController. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33111609/8869493

Comment: preferredFocusedView is deprecated since tvOS 10

Comment: yes, now we have `preferredFocusEnvironments`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifocusenvironment/1648972-preferredfocusenvironments